# Last row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, union-all

I have a query like this

```
select  top 1* from table1 where organizationID= 79 order by D_Index desc
select  top 1* from table1 where organizationID= 87 order by D_Index desc
select  top 1* from table1 where organizationID= 19 order by D_Index desc
```

here i am trying to get last data which is in table 1 against organizationID .. means last data of 79,87 and 19 and also try to combine with union all but this shows an error

```
select  top 1* from table1 where organizationID= 79 order by D_Index desc union all 
select  top 1* from table1 where organizationID= 87 order by D_Index desc union all 
select  top 1* from table1 where organizationID= 19 order by D_Index desc
```

If i wrote this

```
  select  top 1* from table1 where organizationID= 79  union all 
    select  top 1* from table1 where organizationID= 87  union all 
    select  top 1* from table1 where organizationID= 19  
order by D_Index desc
```

then this shows 1st row of 79 and 87 and last row on 19 but i want last rows against 79,87 and 19

any help?

Comment: That is right, it will through an error because an "union all" command will combine the results of any two row sets that is why the query should be scoped first but to solve the current problem using window function will be an efficient one which is available after MS-SQL Server 2012 versions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT
    *,
    row_number() over (partition by organizationID order by D_Index desc) rn
  FROM
    table1
  WHERE organizationID in (19,79,87)
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

Without CTE(as requested)

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  (
    SELECT
      *,
      row_number() over (partition by organizationID order by D_Index desc) rn
    FROM
      table1
    WHERE organizationID in (19,79,87)
  ) x
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: how to do this without CTE?

Comment: @seesharp Just inline the CTE into the query at the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by @t-clausen.dk is the way to go here, but here is a way you can make your current approach work:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table1 WHERE organizationID = 79 ORDER BY D_Index DESC) t1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table1 WHERE organizationID = 87 ORDER BY D_Index DESC) t2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table1 WHERE organizationID = 19 ORDER BY D_Index DESC) t3;
```

The error is happening because `ORDER BY` can't appear in the middle of a union query (or any query).  But if we wrap your queries as subqueries, then we can use `ORDER BY` on them).

Again, using `ROW_NUMBER` is the way to go here, but if you ever need to use such syntax, it is possible if written correctly.